# React : Hide menu on all sub pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `React-router` in my application with something like this in my App.js

```
<Router>
                {location.pathname === "/welcome" ||
                location.pathname === "/login" ||
                location.pathname === "/registration" ||
                location.pathname === "/page/:id?" ? null : (
                    <div>
                        <Menu />
                        <Mobile />
                    </div>
                )}

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/welcome" component={Welcome} />
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path="/page/:id?" component={Page} />
                    <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings}  />
                    <Route exact path="/dash" component={New}/>
                    <Route exact path="/customize/:id?" component={Home} />

                    <Route exact path="/" component={Dash} />
                    <Route component={New}  />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
```

When navigating to normal pages such as `/welcome` and `/login` the menu is effectively hidden, but when browsing to `/page/:id?` the menu is still appearing.

`:id?`  is the custom **id** of the page. How to hide the menu while using a custom id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because location.pathname never is `/page/:id?`. It will look like `/page/123`. So we can update like this:

```
location.pathname.includes("/page") ? null : (<div>...</div>)
```